# How can I use AngularJS directive to apply css style for a string?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have struggle with this problem for days, not knowing how to solve it.

The scenario is:

There is a string from database as `QUESTION`, and another string as `ANSWER`.

```
$scope.exam = {};
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.exam.QUESTION = 'Find the perimeter of a rhombus whose diagonals measure 12 and 16. <br />A.10<br />B.20  <br />C.40 <br />D.80 <br />';
    $scope.exam.ANSWER = 'D';
}, 500);
```

I use regular expression to split the choices of that `QUESTION` and apply css style `button` to the choices.

```
var myArray = /(^.*?)(?:<br ?\/?>)(A\s*?\.[\s\S]*?)(?:<br ?\/?>)(B\s*?\.[\s\S]*?)(?:<br ?\/?>)(C\s*?\.[\s\S]*?)(?:<br ?\/?>)(D\s*?\.[\s\S]*?)(?:<br ?\/?>)?<.*$/mg.exec(question);
```

If that choice is a correct answer, then apply `hvr-bounce-in hvr-sweep-to-right`. Otherwise, apply `hvr-buzz-out` style.

```
ans = "<br /><a ng-class=\"(scope.choiceanswer === v.substring(0, 1)) ? \'hvr-bounce-in hvr-sweep-to-right\':\'hvr-buzz-out\'\">" +v +"</a>";
```

**But all my choices are applied by the same style `hvr-bounce-in hvr-sweep-to-right`.**

How can I solve it?

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [])

    .controller('View2Ctrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.exam = {};
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.exam.QUESTION = 'Find the perimeter of a rhombus whose diagonals measure 12 and 16. <br />A.10<br />B.20  <br />C.40 <br />D.80 <br />';
            $scope.exam.ANSWER = 'D';
        }, 500);


    })
    .directive('choicebutton', function ($compile, $interpolate, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                choiceanswer: '&',
                question: '&',
                choiceClass: '&'
            },
            replace: true,
            link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(scope.question, function (question) {
                    if (question) {
                        var result = "";

                        var ans ='';
                        console.log(question);
                        console.log(scope.choiceanswer());
                        var myArray = /(^.*?)(?:<br ?\/?>)(A\s*?\.[\s\S]*?)(?:<br ?\/?>)(B\s*?\.[\s\S]*?)(?:<br ?\/?>)(C\s*?\.[\s\S]*?)(?:<br ?\/?>)(D\s*?\.[\s\S]*?)(?:<br ?\/?>)?<.*$/mg.exec(question);
                        console.log(myArray.length);
                        angular.forEach(myArray, function (v, l) {
                            console.log(v, l);
                            if (l > 0) {
                                console.log(v.substring(0,1));
                                console.log(scope.choiceanswer() == v.substring(0,1));
                                ans = "<br /><a ng-class=\"(scope.choiceanswer === v.substring(0, 1)) ? \'hvr-bounce-in hvr-sweep-to-right\':\'hvr-buzz-out\'\">" +v +"</a>";
                                
                                console.log(ans);
                                result += ans;

                            }
                        });
                        console.log(result);
                        $timeout(function () {
                            ele.html(result);

                            $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
                        }, 0);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

```html
<link href="http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='View2Ctrl'>
 

<div choicebutton="exam.QUESTION"  class="text-info selectable" choiceanswer="exam.ANSWER" question="exam.QUESTION"  choiceClass="choiceClass"></div>
  
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly in snippet i too many simplified your code, but your variant seems very complicated.

first, if question always have this format, you not need in regex and simple `split` work.

second, you generate string and compile it instead just use built-in `template` for directive.

third, in template string you use wrong `scope` and `v`, because you add it as text, so angular try get it from `scope` and always get *undefined*

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('View2Ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.exam = {};
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.exam.QUESTION = 'Find the perimeter of a rhombus whose diagonals measure 12 and 16. <br />A.10<br />B.20  <br />C.40 <br />D.80 <br />';
      $scope.exam.ANSWER = 'D';
    }, 500);

  })
  .directive('choicebutton', function($compile, $interpolate, $timeout) {
    return {
      template: '<div><span>{{qText}}</span>' +
        '<div ng-repeat="answer in answers">' +
        '    <a ng-class="{\'hvr-bounce-in hvr-sweep-to-right\':answer.selected, \'hvr-buzz-out\':!answer.selected}">{{answer.text}}</a>' +
        '</div></div>',

      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        choiceanswer: '=',
        question: '&',
        choiceClass: '&'
      },
      replace: true,
      link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(scope.question, function(newQuestion, oldQuestion) {
          if (newQuestion === undefined || newQuestion === oldQuestion) return;
          var q = newQuestion.split('<br />');
          scope.qText = q.shift();
          scope.answers = q.map(function(item) {
            return {
              selected: item[0] === scope.choiceanswer,
              text: item
            };
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<link href="http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='View2Ctrl'>


  <div choicebutton="exam.QUESTION" class="text-info selectable" choiceanswer="exam.ANSWER" question="exam.QUESTION" choiceClass="choiceClass"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [])

    .controller('View2Ctrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.exam = {};
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.exam.QUESTION = 'Find the perimeter of a rhombus whose diagonals measure 12 and 16. <br />A.10<br />B.20  <br />C.40 <br />D.80 <br />';
            $scope.exam.ANSWER = 'D';
        }, 500);


    })
    .directive('choicebutton', function ($compile, $interpolate, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                choiceanswer: '&',
                question: '&',
                choiceClass: '&'
            },
            replace: true,
            link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(scope.question, function (question) {
                    if (question) {
                        var result = "";

                        var ans ='';
                        console.log(question);
                        console.log(scope.choiceanswer());
                        var myArray = /(^.*?)(?:<br ?\/?>)(A\s*?\.[\s\S]*?)(?:<br ?\/?>)(B\s*?\.[\s\S]*?)(?:<br ?\/?>)(C\s*?\.[\s\S]*?)(?:<br ?\/?>)(D\s*?\.[\s\S]*?)(?:<br ?\/?>)?<.*$/mg.exec(question);
                        console.log(myArray.length);
                        angular.forEach(myArray, function (v, l) {
                            console.log(v, l);
                            if (l > 0) {
                                console.log(v.substring(0,1));
                                console.log(scope.choiceanswer() == v.substring(0,1));
                                ans = "<br /><a class=\"" + (scope.choiceanswer() === v.substring(0, 1) ? 'hvr-bounce-in hvr-sweep-to-right' : 'hvr-buzz-out') + "\">" +v +"</a>";
                                
                                console.log(ans);
                                result += ans;

                            }
                        });
                        console.log(result);
                        $timeout(function () {
                            ele.html(result);

                            $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
                        }, 0);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

```html
<link href="http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='View2Ctrl'>
 

<div choicebutton="exam.QUESTION"  class="text-info selectable" choiceanswer="exam.ANSWER" question="exam.QUESTION"  choiceClass="choiceClass"></div>
  
  </body>
```

Your issue is the formatting of your `ng-class` attribute.

I believe you were trying to use ternary syntax however `ng-class` does not support such syntax. You provide it with an object hash or map `{'some class to apply': scopeProperty}` where `scopeProperty` is a value that will be evaluated and if truthy will cause the class to be applied.

To use the syntax you are you would `<a class="{{angular expression}}">`. This would also provide you a class that is data bound

Some example in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7u9z2247/

However all of this is defunct in your implementation as your manually compiling it instead of using the template and not implementing any data binding from what i can see. So you can conditionally build your anchor string and apply the class that way, a very JQuery way of doing it.

```
ans = "<br /><a class=\"" + (scope.choiceanswer() === v.substring(0, 1) ? 'hvr-bounce-in hvr-sweep-to-right' : 'hvr-buzz-out') + "\">" +v +"</a>"
```